# MongoDB MongoMapper update embedded document (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

This is driving me insane, and I reached the point where I think I may be using embedded documents wrongly.

```
class User
    include MongoMapper::Document
    key :name, String
    many :businesses
end

class Business
    include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
    key :name, String
    one :address
    many :clients
    belongs_to :user
end

class Address
    include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
    key :name, String
    belongs_to :business
end

class Client
    include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
    key :name, String
    belongs_to :business
end
```

I've created a user and then a business, what I would like to do now is adding an address to the business but I cannot manage to.

The only thing I can think of is finding the user by name or id and then loop through the businesses array, find the business that match by name and set the address...

but to be honest it sounds really lame and I assume there is a more elegant way of doing it.

Thank you

Comment: literally I would like something: set address to something where user.businesses.business.id == something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, when you're embedding, you use `embedded_in` instead of `belongs_to`.

```
class Business
    include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
    key :name, String
    one :address
    many :clients
    embedded_in :user
end

class Address
    include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
    key :name, String
    embedded_in :business
end

class Client
    include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
    key :name, String
    embedded_in :business
end
```

The reason is that, internally, `belongs_to` creates a complicated association proxy that does all sorts of database interactions for non-embedded associations, whereas `embedded_in` simply creates an alias to the `_parent_document` method. `belongs_to` is only for non-embedded associations.

There is not a way to "nicely" query embedded documents.  I think Mongoid lets you pretend that embedded associations are queryable just like regular associations, but MongoMapper doesn't like pretending.  In MongoMapper, an array of embedded documents is, well, just an `Array` [with very little sugar](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/master/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/associations/embedded_collection.rb).  MongoDB may eventually allow virtual collections of embedded documents (it's the [number 1 JIRA issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-142)), and I guess at that point the MM guys will think about something fancier.

In truth, Ruby's enumerable methods are so good that it's not *that* crazy to do the finds yourself.

```
user = User.find("1234567abc")

user.business.select { |b| b.name == target_name }.each { |b| b.address = new_address }

user.save
```